# How can I efficiently read the .txt data by separating by the first delimiter, and the latter separated into an array by delimiters?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a mass raw data file `info.txt`:

```
1 A B F I
2 R S
3 D K L O Q T
...
999998 C X Y Z
999999 D E L
1000000 A Z
```

consisting one `int` followed by one or more `str` values, all separated by a blank space. I want to retrieve a `pandas` DataFrame `df` that has the following format:

```
number   letters
1        [A, B, F, I]
2        [R, S]
3        [D, K, L, O, Q, T]
...
999998   [C, X, Y, Z]
999999   [D, E, L]
1000000  [A, Z]
```

---

What I have performed is the following:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r"../info.txt", header=None)
df.columns = ['number']
df[['number','letters']] = df["number"].str.split(" ", 1, expand=True)
for i in range(len(df)):
    df['letters'][i] = df['letters'][i].split()
```

And this does the trick. The problem is that due to its size, the function takes a little less than two whole minutes.

The one that takes the most time is the `for` loop, the operation that switches each row's `letters` string into an array. Is there a more efficient way to format, maybe even directly while reading the `info.txt`?

(I have explored previous questions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41386443/create-pandas-dataframe-from-txt-file-with-specific-pattern) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61951517/parsing-array-from-txt-file-to-pandas-dataframe-in-python), but I couldn't quite apply them to my data.)

Comment: consider convert the txt file to csv first.

Comment: @LeiYang I have thought about that initially, but since I need my output in a `.txt` form I wondered if I could deal with it directly from `.txt` format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be actually optimized by just reading the file's contents with Python primitives. I suspect `read_csv` attempts do so a bunch of inference and data type magic that's not required for plain data like this.

```
def so_me():
    numbers = []
    letters = []
    with open('./so71567951-data.txt') as f:
        for line in f:
            n, *l = line.rstrip().split()
            numbers.append(int(n))
            letters.append(list(l))
    return pd.DataFrame({'number': numbers, 'letters': letters})
```

This seems to be 50%-60% faster than the other solution (71568114).

I ran out of patience testing the original with the bigger datasets, but over the original this is 43x faster on a 100 000 line dataset.

```
# 5 million lines
name='so_71568114' iters=1 time=9.284 iters_per_sec=0.11
name='so_me' iters=1 time=6.065 iters_per_sec=0.16

# 1.5 million lines
name='so_71568114' iters=1 time=2.911 iters_per_sec=0.34
name='so_me' iters=1 time=1.766 iters_per_sec=0.57

# 100,000 lines
name='so_original' iters=1 time=11.684 iters_per_sec=0.09
name='so_71568114' iters=2 time=0.359 iters_per_sec=5.58
name='so_me' iters=2 time=0.241 iters_per_sec=8.30
```

Comment: completedly agree read with primitives. but where is `71568114` from?

Comment: It's the answer ID of the other answer :)

Comment: it's `12833166` i think.

Comment: That's the answerer's user ID. You can get the answer ID from the share link (`https://stackoverflow.com/a/ANSWER_ID/YOUR_USER_ID`)

Comment: ok. it's good rest api!

Answer (score 2):

Let us optimize your code:

```
s = pd.read_csv('../info.txt', header=None)[0].str.split().str
df_out = pd.DataFrame({'number': s[0], 'letters': s[1:]})
```

---

```
print(df_out)
    number             letters
0        1        [A, B, F, I]
1        2              [R, S]
2        3  [D, K, L, O, Q, T]
3   999998        [C, X, Y, Z]
4   999999           [D, E, L]
5  1000000              [A, Z]
```